# Python integer unexpected results

Tags: python, integer, ironpython

I am using IronPython 2.7 integrated into [Rhinoceros 5](https://www.rhino3d.com/) application.
I am having a strange `int()` function result:

```
import math

angle = 45.0
tangent = math.tan(math.radians(angle))
n = 12*tangent
print "angle: ", angle
print "tangent: ", tangent
print "n: ", n
print "int(n): ", int(n)
```

Results in:

```
angle:  45.0
tangent:  1.0
n:  12.0
int(n):  11
```

So as written above, the `int()` function returns `11` not `12`.
I know there are some floating point number issues, but this should not be related with integers? 
Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thank you for the reply.

EDIT: I added the code, on how I got the "12.0"

Comment: could not reproduce in normal python interpreter and ipython. Why do you suspect 'some floating point number issues'?

Comment: Has Rhinoceros 5 modified the Python interpreter? This looks wrong, and I can't reproduce your issue on a standard 2.7.9 interpreter.

Comment: Works fine for me on 2.7.3

Comment: Works fine for me using Python 2.7

Comment: Works fine in Python 2.7.8

Comment: add the code and how you are using it .

Comment: If you type those two lines into a Python interactive shell, does it print `11`? Or is your figure of `12.0` actually the result of some other floating point operation that *should* yield `12.0`? Can you edit your code into the above question, please.

Comment: @marco, I  reopened the question, you need to add the  code that you are using that causes the issue so it can be replicated.

Comment: Any chance of linking to actual compiled interpreter which has such issue?

Comment: @marco, it was a dupe, nowhere are you calling `int(12.0)`, you are seeing the str.format representation of the float

Comment: `12 * math.tan(math.radians(45.0))` equals `11.999999999999998`, not `12`. Printing value limits precision.

Comment: @PadraicCunnigham, I apologize. My intention was not to scam anyone, I just thought that int(12.0) and int( 12*math.tan(math.radians(angle)) ) is the same.
So ForceBlue's answer bellow is correct?

Comment: The first code you posted was wrong. But this one works OK and _shows the behavior you're talking about_.

Comment: Thank you ForceBru, and apologizes for the initial mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You got 11.9999999999999982 !

---

If you add the following line to your code, you'll get an amazing result

```
print "%.16f" % n
```

Output

```
11.9999999999999982
```

#### How to solve

---

You may want to try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

k=Decimal(12.0)
print int(k) #prints 12
```

This will convert `12.0` (a float) to a `Decimal` value. This approach can solve some issues related to floats.

#### Why it happened

---

You could read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and see that, for example, `2.675` can be represented as  `2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875` because of some limitations.

In your case you've got a number that's *close to 12*. That's why `int` rounded it to 11. For example:

```
>>> int(11.9999999999)==11
True
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you didn't answer any of the question

Comment: under no circumstances should `int(12.0)` become `11`

Comment: Your edits still don't answer the question. The OP is not experiencing floating point errors, the issue is `int(12.0)` becomes `11`. Also what OS would represent 12 as 11.999999?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I've edited my answer so it could explain it better

Comment: @ForceBru, it is still not answering the question. Where are you addressing rhino or ironpython's role in all this? `print(int(12.0))` under *no* circumstances should output `11`

Comment: @ForceBru: your "Why it happened"-section is speculation, and not _that_ convincing. There's no point in representing 12.0 as 11.9999999

Comment: @knitti, but it may be, as you can see from the code in my answer

Comment: @ForceBru: No, you've shown that `int(11.99999999)` will give `11` not that `12.0` could be represented as `11.99999999`

Comment: then it isn't an answer but a speculation. What part of an OS' representation of a number is used by python? -> This is the part where the bug is. And relates in this specific case most probably to the way python has been linked to a bugged library while being embedded into the application

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, @knitti, it's now clear why the OP got such results. He wasn't doing `int(12.0)`. He was performing some math before. That's why I was forced to speculate.

Comment: @ForceBru, you should not speculate and your reasoning was completely wrong.  if the question needs more info ask for it, the last part of your answer should also be edited or removed.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, you're right. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the error is occurring in the `tan` operation, and your confusion is arising because of the way that `print` tries to make the output more readable:

```
>>> math.tan(math.radians(angle))
0.9999999999999999
>>> print(math.tan(math.radians(angle)))
1.0
```

The easiest solution is to use round instead of int:

```
import math

angle = 45.0
tangent = math.tan(math.radians(angle))
n = 12*tangent
print "angle: ", angle
print "tangent: ", tangent
print "n: ", n
print "round(n,0): ", round(n,0)
```

Yields:

```
angle:  45.0
tangent:  1.0
n:  12.0
round(n,0):  12.0
```

As ForceBru mentioned, there is a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module to help with floating-point operations, but I've found to be quite cumbersome, and rounding at the end of the calculation is normally sufficient.